Scatterplot in stata gone wrong. What's wrong with my code?
twoway (scatter percentlessthan35 percent55andup) (function y = x, range(.1490401 1) lc(red)), legend(off)

So basically i expected it to be scattered? I don't know where I went wrong.
Other notes: range(.1490401 1) is the range for percentlessthan35 (so i can make a line).

My guess is that nothing is wrong with your code.
You should be looking at your data.
Your two variables plot on the line y = 1  - x, or equivalently y + x = 1.
Two variables that are supposedly "percents" (but really proportions between 0 and 1) are just complementary. From the names. there may be a third variable that happens to have values of 0 in practice.

saw where i went wrong with this guidance!
